# what are pros and cons of using database schemas in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

The app, I am working on is like flikr but with groups concept. Each group consists of multiple users and user can do activities like upload,share,comment etc. within their group only.

I am thinking of creating a schema per group to organized data under group-name namespace in order to manage it easily & efficiently.

```
Will it have any adverse effect on database backup plans ?

Is there any practical limits on number of schemas per database ?
```

Comment: http://www.postgresqlforbeginners.com/2010/12/schema.html

Comment: schemas are good for logical organization, for allowing user access based on schema, for back ups, where you can just choose to backup a particular schema, and a good few other things. I am struggling to think of any real disadvantages.

Comment: @JohnBarça , I guess,it will have advantages on query performance too   since table will not be much populated.

Answer (score 1):

When splitting identically-structured data into schemas, you need to anticipate the fact that you won't need to query them as global entities again. Because it's as cumbersome and anti-SQL as having them in different tables of the same schema.

As an example, say you have 100 groups of users, in 100 schemas named `group1..group100`, each with a `photo` table.

To get the total number of photos in your system, you'd need to do:

```
select sum(n) FROM
(
select count(*) as n from group1.photos
UNION
select count(*) as n from group2.photos
UNION
select count(*) as n from group3.photos
...
UNION
select count(*) as n from group100.photos
)
```

This sort of query or view needs also to be rebuilt any time a group is added or removed.

This is neither easy or efficient, it's a programmer's nightmare.

Comment: Yes, I admit that querying across schemas will be painfull & not efficient too, but except for statistics it has no use-case.

Comment: @Daniel. If each group is logically separate within the application design, why would you want to run such a query? You can always keep a meta table for all photos, if you need such a thing.

Comment: @JohnBarça, will it have any impact on database backups ?

Comment: You can use the schema switch (-n) to pg_dump to only backup certain schemas or just back up all schemas. So it is more flexible, but will have no impact if you decide to backup everything.

Comment: @JohnBarça, only thing which is cumbersome is schema change & it will require a big effort !! , Do you know if there is any practical limit of no of schemas per database ?